# replace values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I'm trying to do a last access date and time for a website when a user choose a key from a dictionary in a dictionary value.

here is the code:

```
import webbrowser, time

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
web_pages = {1:('Google Scholar','webpage','N/A'),
             2:('Moodle','webpage','N/A'),
             3:('BBC','webpage','N/A'),
             4:('Webmail','webpage','N/A')} 

##------last access date-------------------------
def last_access(x, y):
    ([x] +" "*10+ value[0] +" "*10 +value[1]+" "*10 +[y]+"\n")

##-------output_structure_top---------------------------
def output_structure_top ():
    print "--- MY BOOKMARK MANAGER --- "+"\n"  
    print "Number"+" "*10 +"Name"+" "*30+"Address"+" "*20+"Last accessed"
    print "-"*90+"\n"

##----output_structure_bottom------------------------
def output_structure_bottom():
    print "-"*60+"\n"

while True:
    ui = raw_input("""Enter the number to open a bookmark,
    or enter + to add, - to delete, or x to exit: \n """)
    litems = len(web_pages)
    if ui >= litems:
        ui = int(ui)
        la = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))+" "+(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

        url = (web_pages[ui][1]) #get the url from the web_pages

        webbrowser.open(url)   #opens the url in a web browser

        output_structure_top()    #print out the top table structure

        last_access(int(ui), la)   #gets the date and time and replaces is it instead of N/A

        output_structure_bottom() #print out the bottom table structure

else:
    print "invalid input!"
    break
`
```

What I get is this:

```
   ([x] +" "*10+ value[0] +" "*10 +value[1]+" "*10 +[y]+"\n")
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

what I'm expecting:

If the user select key 2 it will open the url in a browser and prints out:

```
   --- MY BOOKMARK MANAGER ---

  Number__________Name_________________Address_________last accessed

  1__________Google Scholar______________webpage_______N/A

  2__________Moodle__________webpage__________08/11/2014 17:40:19

  3__________BBC__________webpage__________N/A

  4__________Webmail__________webpage__________N/A

  ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: where is the "value" list coming from, and why do you use [x] instead of x?

Comment: You can also call the `str()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` are strings, then replace:

```
([x] +" "*10+ value[0] +" "*10 +value[1]+" "*10 +[y]+"\n")
```

by:

```
(x +" "*10+ value[0] +" "*10 +value[1]+" "*10 +y+"\n")
```